# Store Firestore objects in Android ViewModel

Tags: android, design-patterns, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel

I'm creating a new Android project, using Kotlin, ViewModels, DataBinding and Firestore. I'm a bit confused how I should go forward with this, mainly how to handle/store Firestore documents/references. As example, I will use a GroceryList app, in which you can add items to your list.

At some point, you select one of your lists, and go to some `DetailFragment`. I store my selected `GroceryList` in a `selectedGroceryList` object in my ViewModel. In my xml, I can use this object in ViewModel to display the name, the items in the list, etc. For instance, I can display the name in a textview with `android:text="@{viewModel.selectedGroceryList.name}"`.

Up to this point, I'm a happy! However.. what if we want to write?

Imagine I want to add 'Apples' to my grocerylist. I can add it to the `groceryList` in the ViewModel, but that doesn't add it to my Firestore. To do that, I would need the Firestore `Documentreference`. So what is the best way to save this Firestore docref? Should I save this ref to my ViewModel next to the `groceryList`, and always store the object itself, and the reference to it? Or should I only store the reference, and fetch the object from my Firestore db every time I need it?

Comment: If you are interested, I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can create a shopping list app using Cloud Firestore and Android.

Comment: That looks good, @AlexMamo. Will certainly watch some parts of that. Would you care to explain how you handled the problem above, saving references and/or parsed objects?

Comment: Give it a try, cheers!